# Pulling existing project settings from .teamcity folder in VCS to new TeamCity Server

Tags: teamcity

I've configured our current TeamCity instance to use Versioned Settings and these have been pushed to the .teamcity folder at the root of our repository.

I'm now configuring a new TeamCity instance and would like to set the VCS root of the _Root project to be my current repo and have it synchronise  in all the current settings.

I've configured the VCS on the Root Project, and enabled versioned settings which informs me that the repo contains project definitions and would I like to import them. I choose to import them and this results in me getting the following error message.

**Current Status:**

[13:16:17]: 
 Failed to apply changes from VCS to project settings (revision 40715d54dc3d66486e90eaec9d105809dfe0224e): Remove of the project where versioned settings are defined via commit is not supported, you can remove the '<Root project>' project in UI. Please fix the errors in VCS and commit again.

Now the message suggests that I should delete the <Root project>, which doesn't seem correct. I'm guessing the issue is that the .teamcity folder already contains a definition for the Root Project and somehow this is conflicting with the new Root project.

Is what I'm trying to achieve here possible?

Comment: As the log message suggests, this scenario is not supported yet. I guess the best solution would be if there was a child project, but not the root one.

Comment: I had similar problems and I'm my problem stemmed from me having VCS settings on the project as well as on a sub-project and TeamCity didn't like one repo being used by multiple projects - in the version controlled config files at least the VCS root was only connected to one of the projects which didn't match what was in TeamCity.